# (Z3Py) Using all_smt to generate all solutions of a model

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py, theorem-proving

The online [Programming Z3 book](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-blocking-evaluations) contains a full implementation of an `all_smt` function that generate an iterator of all valid solutions for a model. I am using this `all_smt` function verbatim, as well as a naive implementation `all_smt_slow_method` that performs the same thing. My `all_smt_slow_method` function produces the correct answer, while `all_smt` produces an incorrect answer. I suspect that the available `all_smt` implementation is correct, and that I'm calling it wrong somehow.

The problem:

```
1. x, y, z are integers between 0 and 11, inclusive.

2. The difference between x and y must be less than or equal to 8

3. The difference between y and z must be less than or equal to 8

How many valid (x, y, z) pairs satisfy the above constraints?
```

My solution:

```
from z3 import *


def all_smt(s, initial_terms):
    def block_term(s, m, t):
        s.add(t != m.eval(t, model_completion=True))

    def fix_term(s, m, t):
        s.add(t == m.eval(t, model_completion=True))

    def all_smt_rec(terms):
        if sat == s.check():
            m = s.model()
            yield m
            for i in range(len(terms)):
                s.push()
                block_term(s, m, terms[i])
                for j in range(i):
                    fix_term(s, m, terms[j])
                yield from all_smt_rec(terms[i:])
                s.pop()

    yield from all_smt_rec(list(initial_terms))


def all_smt_slow_method(s, initial_terms, x, y, z):
    s.add(initial_terms)
    manual_counter = 0
    while s.check() == sat:
        s.add(Or(x != s.model()[x], y != s.model()[y], z != s.model()[z]))
        manual_counter += 1
    return manual_counter


def main():
    maximum_delta = 8
    range = 12
    x, y, z = Ints("x y z")
    initial_terms = [
        0 <= x,
        x < range,
        0 <= y,
        y < range,
        0 <= z,
        z < range,
    ]
    initial_terms += [
        x - y <= maximum_delta,
        y - x <= maximum_delta,
        y - z <= maximum_delta,
        z - y <= maximum_delta,
    ]

    manual_counter = all_smt_slow_method(Solver(), initial_terms, x, y, z)

    all_smt_generator = all_smt(Solver(), initial_terms)
    all_smt_counter = sum(1 for x in all_smt_generator)

    print(f"{range ** 3 = } {manual_counter = } {all_smt_counter = }")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`manual_counter` evaluates to 1468, which I believe be the correct answer. The result of all_smt has a size of 111, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the `all_smt` method isn't quite right. Use it like this instead:

```py
s = Solver()
s.add(initial_terms)
all_smt_generator = all_smt(s, [x, y, z])
```

That is, you should first create a solver, add the constraints, and then pass it to `all_smt` as the first argument. The second argument is the list of variables. (In general they can be arbitrary expressions, but for all-smt, you should pass the set of variables you care about. The way you called it, you essentially counted how many different assignments can be made so your constraints themselves can take different values. It'd be interesting to check that number is indeed 111, though I do trust z3 that should indeed be the case.)

If you modify your program like this, you'll see both methods produce the correct count of 1468 solutions.

*Side note* Even though what you wrote is equivalent, using `Abs` would make your solution clearer. That is, instead of writing `[x - y <= maximum_delta, y - x <= maximum_delta]`, you can shorten it to `Abs(x - y) <= maximum_delta`. And similarly for `y` and `z`.

There's no built-in method to indicate a constraint of the form `a <= b < c`. But you can create one yourself. Just define:

```py
# CO: Closed on the left, Open on the right range
def inCORange (left, x, right):
   return And(left <= x, x < right)
```

and use it as you wish. This is in fact how you use z3py most of the time, by writing these helper functions that construct z3 constraints for you.

Comment: Thank you for much! And good tip on `Abs()`. I initially tried python's built-in `abs()`, got a syntax error, and gave up. BTW, is there a good replacement for `0 <= x, x < range`? Python's own `0 <= x < range` obviously doesn't work in this case, but some sort of syntax sugar similar to it would be nice.

Comment: You typically write helper functions to simplify generation of more complicated constraints. I added an example to my answer which I hope should clarify.