Z3 SMT Solver : Is there a way to generate a Model with a Specific Set of Variables
I'm working on a problem where I have a large number of variables (around 500) defined in Z3. I'm interested in finding a multiple models ( working on multiple solutions ) that satisfies my constraints, but I only need the values of a specific subset of these variables.
Is there a way to instruct Z3 to check the constraints and generate a model that only includes specific set of variables? I'm looking for a solution that would avoid generating values for all 500 variables, as this is unnecessary for my problem and could potentially slow down the solver.
Any advice or guidance with simple example would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
I am using following approach ( a simple example ) like below for my project.
The API model would get solution for all variables but interested in generating a model with specific variables. While getting all solutions, it slows down.
# Define a large number of variables
variables = [Int('x{}'.format(i)) for i in range(500)]

# Define some constraints
constraints = [var > 0 for var in variables]

# Create a solver and add the constraints
s = Solver()
s.add(constraints)

# Find 500 solutions
for i in range( 500 ):
    if s.check() == sat:
        m = s.model()

        # Print the values of x0, x1, and x2
        for j in range(3):
            print(m[variables[j]])

        # Add a constraint that negates the current solution for x0, x1, and x2
        s.add(Or(variables[0] != m[variables[0]], variables[1] != m[variables[1]], variables[2] != m[variables[2]]))
    else:
        print("No more solutions")
        break


In general, you need not worry about variables that don't contribute to a solution: If they do not matter, then the underlying solver will figure that out and won't waste its time in determining whether the problem is SAT or UNSAT. (During model creation, it'll assign values to these variables, but that's a relatively cheap operation once you get to a SAT state.)
It seems to me, however, what you want is a bit different. You're saying that even though change in these "extra" variables can give you a new model, you don't really care about those. In your example, the only interesting models to you are when x0, x1, and x2 are different. That is, you don't care about differing models where x0, x1, x2 are the same and the changes are in the remaining 497 variables.
If that's the case (and that's a legitimate use case indeed), you should use the fast all-sat algorithm instead. See https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-blocking-evaluations, and in particular the function all_smt. (Also see (Z3Py) checking all solutions for equation)
In particular, the second argument to all_smt (named initial_terms) is exactly what you want to use. You want to pass [x0, x1, x2] as an argument to that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76494971/936310 for a discussion on the correct use of all_smt.

Thank you for the valuable information. Based on your information, it appears that the get_model() function is generally considered less expensive once the check() function has been executed.
However, in our specific project, we've observed that get_model() is more expensive than check(), taking almost twice as long. Here's a brief overview of the data in z3
No variables- Integer-105  Boolean-606 Total- 711 , Pseudo Bool Variables- 2548, Total Variables-3259 Number of assertions: 3379

In a simple use case, we're looking to generate 200 combinations using 5 out of the 711 variables. We've tried the all_smt method and here are the performance numbers:

Total time for 200 check() calls: 0.872 seconds
Total time for 200 get_model calls: 1.5 seconds
The size of the model for each check is approximately 3500

Given these numbers, it's clear that get_model() is the more expensive operation and this is a cause for concern. We're interested in finding ways to reduce the time taken by get_model() so that it's less than or equal to the time taken by check().

Here are some solver statistics for reference:
(:added-eqs           69574
:arith-eq-adapter    3
:arith-diseq         812
:arith-lower         408
:arith-make-feasible 260
:arith-max-columns   707
:arith-upper         1016
:binary-propagations 1139519
:conflicts           79
:decisions           258943
:del-clause          48

final-checks        202
:max-memory          33.48
:memory              32.75
:minimized-lits      129
:mk-bool-var         10978
:mk-clause           6226
:mk-clause-binary    40443
:num-allocs          11929426139.00
:num-checks          202
:propagations        1304134
:rlimit-count        5496682
:time                0.00);

Numbers like 0.8s, 1.5s are really in the noise. The overhead of z3py can by itself account for that. If you really want/need the speed, you'll have to code directly in C,  I'm afraid.

200 get_model calls, 1.5 seconds corresponds to 7.5 milliseconds for each call. Just shuttling that call from z3py to C and back would account for that. Note that the result of a check is a simple sat/unsat/unknown answer, which would be fairly fast to get back into python space, as opposed to the model-conversion the z3py layer has to do for getting the model back into Python.

The numbers mentioned here are from c++ code directly. We are not using python for our  project.

Why did you tag the question z3py then? Please tag with c/c++ to be clear.

I apologize for  the confusion and I have updated the same.

No worries. It’s impossible to opine any further without seeing the actual code. The usual route is to profile your code, and if the bottleneck is in a z3 call, you can post a minimal-reproducible example here to ask for advice or directly ask developers at: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/discussions
